# Shell script - knowing the path of an include, then include another file

Tags: shell, sh, posix

### What I want?

I'm dealing with a lot of scripts so, I try to put repetitive tasks in differents files and scripts that I'll include on demand.

### Details

NO bash, just POSIX shell, the interpreter will be /bin/sh, script will be run from anywhere, not only from his own folder, includes can be anywhere too, but can be relative.

### File structure:

```
.
-- folder1
|   \ main.sh
-- folder2
|   \ incl1.sh
-- folder3
    \ incl2.sh
```

### File contents:

main.sh:

```
THIS_FILE=$(readlink -f "${0}");
BASEDIR=$(dirname "${THIS_FILE}");
. "${BASEDIR}/incl1/incl1.sh";
```

incl1.sh:

```
. pathThatIDontKnow/incl2.sh
```

incl2.sh, content is not relevant, just needs to be included in incl1.sh

### More details:

The problem is in incl1, i cant include incl2 without knowing my current path, and is not possible to include incl2 on main.sh.

Is important to note that can be a new file main2.sh that tries to include same files in same way, this includes are not exclusive for main.sh and is not necesary to be in same folder as main.sh.

Any thoughts? this is technically possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just find out what the path to `incl2.sh` is?

Comment: @red cricket as i said, incl2 can be relative to incl1 but main is not aware of incl2 functionality will be used in incl1

Comment: I would avoid relative paths.

Comment: @RedCricket impossible to avoid relative paths if you target different systems or configurations

Comment: No, it is not impossible and relative paths have the same issues as absolute paths.  In the end you need to know where your files are.  If you don't you're screwed either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after thinking this a little, in my opinion, I can't solve this in the way I think in first place, so I attack the problem from other point of view: defining in every system a a scripts' root path variable as global.

So I export a global variable like this:

```
export SCRIPT_ROOT=path/to/root/scripts
```

It can be defined in different places such a profile.d.

Then in incl1 I'll put the import line like this:

```
. "$SCRIPT_ROOT/folder3/incl2.sh";
```

$SCRIPTS_ROOT can be used from everywhere.

I hope this helps someone else.